# Ruby: Sorting an Array, skipping the first element

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, ruby-1.8

I want to sort an Array of Arrays of Strings by the first String skipping the first Array but I just don't have an idea how to do it using the build-in `sort` method. I could copy the whole array without the first element and sort the resutling Array then but isn't there a more elegant way to do this?

```
ar = [["zzzz", "skip", "this"], ["EFP3","eins","eins"], ["EFP10","zwei","zwei"], ["EFP1","drei","drei"]]
ar.sort!{ |a,b|
  if a == ar.first   # why doesn't 
    next             # this
  end                # work ?

  # compare length, otherwise it would be e.g. 10 < 3
  if a[0].length == b[0].length
    a[0] <=> b[0]
  else
    a[0].length <=> b[0].length
  end
}
```

I want to have the result like this:

```
["zzzz", "skip", "this"], ["EFP1","drei","drei"], ["EFP3","eins","eins"], ["EFP10","zwei","zwei"]
```

sortet by `"EFP#"`

**edit:** I'm using Ruby 1.8, if it matters.

Answer (score 5):

```
ar[1..-1].sort { whatever you want }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way:

```
[ar.first] + ar[1..-1].sort{ |a,b| a[0] <=> b[0] }
# => [["zzzz", "skip", "this"], ["EFP1", "drei", "drei"], ["EFP10", "zwei", "zwei"], ["EFP3", "eins", "eins"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

> but isn't there a more elegant way to do this?

You could [`sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-sort) the other elements and re-[assign](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) them:

```
ar = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

ar[1..-1] = ar[1..-1].sort

ar #=> [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

> I want to have the result [...] sortet by `"EFP#"`

[`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) looks like the right tool:

```
ar = [["zzzz", "skip"], ["EFP3", "eins"], ["EFP10", "zwei"], ["EFP1", "drei"]]

ar[1..-1] = ar[1..-1].sort_by { |s, _| s[/\d+/].to_i }

ar #=> [["zzzz", "skip"], ["EFP1", "drei"], ["EFP3", "eins"], ["EFP10", "zwei"]]
```

`s[/\d+/].to_i` extracts the digits from `s` and converts it to an integer:

```
"EFP1"[/\d+/].to_i  #=> 1
"EFP3"[/\d+/].to_i  #=> 3
"EFP10"[/\d+/].to_i #=> 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have explained how to get the right answer.

As for why it doesn't work, sort simply doesn't expect "next". "next" is a language construct intended for a normal loop. `sort`, however, is a function that repeatedly asks another function for a result. As a normal Ruby function, it can't detect if you returned "next" because that's the equivalent of returning nil (or leaving the body empty). And so, it can't have, and doesn't have, any conventions about how to handle a "next" instance.

It causes an error because nil is not a valid number to return from the |a,b| comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison returns -1, 0 or 1, so if you return 1 for the first it is sorted as the first element, as 1 it would become the last element.

```
ar.sort!{ |a,b|
  if a == ar.first
    -1
  elsif a[0].length == b[0].length # compare length, otherwise it would be e.g. 10 < 3
    a[0] <=> b[0]
  else
    a[0].length <=> b[0].length
  end
}

#=>[["zzzz", "skip", "this"], ["EFP1", "drei", "drei"], ["EFP3", "eins", "eins"], ["EFP10", "zwei", "zwei"]]
```